# How to convert cell of tables into single table in matlab

Tags: matlab, struct, cell

After loading Excel tables, a variables E contains cells of tables.

```
DIR=C:\Documents\myFiles
cd(DIR)

for i=1:3
     a=rand(3,1)
     b=rand(3,1)
     T=table(a,b)
     FN=strcat('B',num2str(i))
     save(FN,'T')
end

D=dir('*.mat')
for j=1:3
     E{j}=load(D(j).name )
end

A=vertcat(E{:})
```

The last step of conversion is not working. How it can be modified?

Comment: Why is `% Not working on Matlab 2017`? explodes? sends your data to Mars? Why is it not working?

Comment: it converts into struct of tables and not into single table.

Comment: Wait, are these tables? according to the docs it should return a numeric matrix.

Comment: These excel files are table format saved with writetable command

Comment: Can you give a [mcve]

Comment: This is a very different example than usin `xlsread`. `load` returns different outputs than `xlsread`. Which one you want?

Comment: This is final code and expects Ans with 'load' command.

Comment: So you want the answer with `load`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works:

```
A=[];
for j=1:3
     E=load(D(j).name);
     A=vertcat(A,E.T);
end
```

If you rather have the load and the concatenation separated, then just

```
A=[];
for ii=1:3
     A=vertcat(A,E{ii}.T);
end
```